# Как зарегистрировать адрес кошелька hash, к примеру для TRON, в блокчейне без всяких бирж и кошельков?

Tags: криптовалюта

То-есть, есть же блокчейн это программы копии которых установлены у майнеров так вот как там создается новый кошелек? Эти то кошельки типа Metamask-а это уже упрощенная система, но они то обращаются как, то к блокчейну и регистрируют новый пустой кошелек приватный ключ и публичный и уже отображают его у себя клиенту публичный, а при отправке за клиента Metamask использует приватный ключ клиента?

А нужно как то зарегистрироваться в сети Tron, чтобы получить эти ключи и самому подписывать транзакцию приватным ключом как это сделать?

Есть наверно какой API?